# Change Theme in Bravana Template

Tags: html, css, templates, themes

i ordered Bravana Template
http://demo.thedevelovers.com/business/bravana-v1.3/

but there is less documentation attached.
Does someone know how i can change the default green theme to theme 'gold'?

In the header i found:
!-- THEME CSS --
link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
link href="assets/css/my-custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

but in the main.css i can not find where i can change the theme from green to gold.

thanks in advance!
Mike

Comment: here is live demo:
http://demo.thedevelovers.com/business/bravana-v1.3/template/index.html
in this demo you can change the skin color by yourself; but i want to change the color by html code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i found out by myself ;)
Skin file must be placed below main.css